# Optimal fan placment? -room layout

Tags: fans, bedroom

[image]

The door is always closed. The dark green means possible placement on the floor. Should the fan point inward, outward, at the wall? Thanks!

Comment: `The door is always closed` ... how do you get into the room?

Comment: you question makes absolutely no sense and it is pointless ... you are the only one that can decide if the fan is working in the way that you want it to work

Comment: It’s entirely “opinion based”.

Comment: @Tyson Isn’t every answer on this site “opinion based”?

Comment: @LeeSam text from the close vote page sums it up best, there is similar, but sadly not identical, text in the help center. “Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fans are used for 1) circulation, and/or 2) cooling.

1) without adequate circulation, mold and mildew can develop, especially in a damp environment. Areas that are most likely to inhibit circulation are low areas between the bed and wall and in the closet (if closed off with a door).

Therefore, I’d recommend your location by the window. In fact, I think I’d point the fan slightly towards the closet and bed so it circulates the air in a swirling motion around the room.

2) When Air is blown across your skin, it creates a cooling effect. So, I also like the area by the window. The area on the table might be too close and cause discomfort. The area on the floor would be partially blocked by the table.